# При вызове хука на уничтожение окна не происходит запись в файл

Tags: c++, windows, hook

```
SetWindowsHookEx( WH_CBT, func, dll, 0)
```

Вызывает функцию, срабатывающую при уничтожении окна:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HCBT_DESTROYWND)
    {
        FILE* file;
        fopen_s(&file, "C:\\file.txt", "a+");
        if( file == NULL )
            MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Can't open"), TEXT("File"), MB_ICONERROR);
        fprintf(file, "chaa\n");
        fclose(file);
    }
    return (CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam));
}
```

Функция и проверка на уничтожение срабатывает, но при этом не происходит записи в файл. При этом он существует и доступен для чтения/записи. Почему так? И ещё маленький вопрос: на какие окна срабатывает *HCBT_DESTROYWND*? Когда закрываешь проводник, либо косынку/*paint* вызова функции не происходит.

Comment: Пробовал использовать *fstream* - результат тот же

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> fopen_s(&file, "C:\\file.txt", "a+");
> ```

Не надо без админских прав писать в корень системного диска.

Измени путь на такой, который

- точно доступен для записи пользователю без админских прав
- не подпадает под системную виртуализацию
- не зависит от текущего каталога

Comment: Спасибо большое, долго не мог понять. Ни разу не замечал чтобы Винда блокировала файлы на системном диске за исключением некоторых папок

Comment: @ProstoNekitos, просто корень системного диска входит в эти несколько папок.